# Continuous/constant autoplay speed with iDangerous Swiper

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

I want to achieve a continuous/constant speed while autoplaying through the slides. It is easy by just setting the CSS transition-timing-function of .swiper-wrapper to linear:

```
.swiper-wrapper
{
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

But in Internet Explorer Edge 41.16299.611.0 the animation stutters even on fast computers? Is there a fix for IE? Or maybe there is an other possibility to achieve an not accelerating autoplay with iDangerous Swiper?

Here I made a little codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gdOGNw

I used following Swiper configuration:

```
{
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  spaceBetween: 0,
  loop: true,
  speed: 5000,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 0,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
  },
}
```

Comment: It works fine if you set `slidesPerView` to a value bigger than 5

Comment: Nice idea! Had to set higher value to get it smooth. It depends on display's width..

Answer (score 1):

The owner of this library thinks Internet Explorer is not *"modern"* (because it doesn't fully support ES6 syntax). I qoute:

> Swiper is not compatible with all platforms, it is a modern touch slider which is focused only on modern apps/platforms to bring the best experience and simplicity.

Furthermore, [he states](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/2282#issuecomment-339916862):

> Swiper ES module should be transpiled with Babel or Buble to ES5 syntax.

So, if you want to use the library in a browser that doesn't support ES6, you need to transpile it to ES5.

Comment: Did you try it? Tried transpiling with babel but I got ReferenceError: Swiper is not defined?

Comment: He is right about IE 